# Bootstrap drop down button will not work when adding link

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

A Bootstrap drop down menu has been created. I have used jQuery, Bootstrap for this. The links are working on the menu when not in a drop down, but when they are in a drop down, the links are not redirecting to whatever page, I have set. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Test<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Places</li>
    <li><a id="link1" href="link.php#">Link II</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="linktwo.php">Link III</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have this in the script section:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("link1").click(function() {
    window.location = pageLink.concat('link=true');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link2").click(function() {
    window.location = pageLink.concat('changeChar=true');
  });
});
```

Comment: Typo: `$("link1")` should be `$("#link1")`  Also, what is `pageLink`?

Answer (score 2):

Trigger Function

`$()` = Jquery

`$().on()` = Which action you want to trigger

`$().on('click')` = Listen and Trigger

- You want to trigger element class "student":

it will be ::

```
$('.student').on('change', function(){ returnMe(this.value); })
```

Answer (score 1):

to select the ID from HTML elements we use `#id_name`
you didn't use the `#` to select the `link1` element

use
 `$("#link1").click(function(){`

 insted of`$("link1").click(function(){`